# Convert JSON file to CSV file using jq

Tags: json, linux, csv, jq

i have JSON file called myresponse.json.

```
"status":"CONTENT",
"valid":true,
"success":true,
"failure":false,
"content":{
  "id":0,"resources":[{

  "id":0,"value":52.51742935180664
  },
 {
  "id":1,"value":13.392845153808594
  },
 {
  "id":5,"value":"2021-02-09T13:15:15Z"
  },
 {
  "id":6,"value":20.754192352294922
  }]}}}


"status":"CONTENT",
    "valid":true,
    "success":true,
    "failure":false,
    "content":{
      "id":0,"resources":[{
    
      "id":0,"value":52.51742935180664
      },
     {
      "id":1,"value":13.392845153808594
      },
     {
      "id":5,"value":"2021-02-09T13:15:15Z"
      },
     {
      "id":6,"value":20.754192352294922
      }]}}}
```

obtained with a curl.

how can i use jq to convert json to csv file where "0,1,5,6" must be the columns and the values ​​of "0,1,5,6" must respectively occupy each row of the csv file, like this:

```
  0,1,5,6

  52.51742935180664, 13.392845153808594, "2021-02-09T13:15:15Z", 20.754192352294922
  52.51742935180664, 13.392845153808594, "2021-02-09T13:15:15Z", 20.754192352294922
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The rxtract is not valid json.

Comment: how can i get a valid json? the script bash with curl is: while true;

do curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://172.17.0.2:8080/api/clients/giammi-VirtualBox/6/0 >> myresponse.json

sleep 1s

done

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes the input consists of a stream of valid JSON objects along the lines shown in the question.

If the relevant values of .id are known beforehand, then generating the header row is trivial, and a  solution implemented with flexibility in mind is as follows:

```
def oneline:
  .content.resources
  | INDEX(.[]; .id) | map_values(.value);

def emit($keys):
  [.[ $keys[] ]];
  
[0,1,5,6] as $keys
| $keys,
  (inputs | oneline | emit($keys))
| join(",")
```

Since this relies on `inputs` to read the input, jq should be invoked with the -r and -n options (e.g. `jq -rn -f program.jq`)

#### Using the first object to determine the relevant .id values

If the relevant values of .id are determined by the first JSON object in the stream, the above defs can be reused with the following:

```
(input | oneline) as $first
| ($first | keys) as $keys
| $keys,
  ($first | emit($keys)),
  (inputs | oneline | emit($keys))
| join(",")
```

This solution would be used with jq's -r and -n options.